# iPhone Address Book - Actual Addresses

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, abaddressbook

I'm trying to retrieve all the addresses from the address book and display them in a tableview, but I am having trouble understanding the structure of the dictionary for which street addresses are returned. Does anyone know of a tutorial or relevant code snippet for extracting the street address(es) of contacts in the AddressBook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explanation with example:[AddressBook programming](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/AccessingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001023-BABHHIHC)

You might want to retrieve kABAddressStreetKey from the kABAddressProperty

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, the link you want is [the iOS version](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html).  There's an AddressBook framework for iOS and one for Mac OS, so they have separate documentation.  It has a section on street addresses in the second chapter.